# Meaning of question mark in html meta content

Tags: html, meta

On some websites source html files, I have seen some snippets like this in the `head` section :

`<meta property="og:image" content="data/avatars/13181.jpg?1588606964" />`

I don't quite understand the meaning of the question mark here. The only thing I can think of is using `?` combined with `=` to add parameters with values to a URL, but this is not the case here because there is no `=`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a URL GET parameter, as you allude to. Only it’s one with a name but no value. It’s purpose is to clear any caches when the linked file is changed, by also changing the parameter at that time. To do so, the parameter is a version number, a timestamp of the last change to the file, or a hash of its contents.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer. Hope it has become clearer. You don’t want the file cached when it changes.